# Why does System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory() throw InvalidDataException on Artifact.zip from TeamCity?

Tags: wpf, teamcity, zip, system.io.compression

I recently updated Jetbrains Team City to version 2020.2.2.  I use it to build my project whenever I check code into my source repository.  I use the TeamCity API to DownloadAll in order to retrieve an Artifacts.zip that contains all the files generated by the build.

The recent update has a bug in it which is corrupting the Artifacts.zip file that is downloaded.

I am now getting an **InvalidDataException "A local file header is corrupt."** when My program calls `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory()` on the Artifacts.zip file.

I am able to right click on this very same file and unzip it using the built in windows "Extract All" and also with 7-Zip extract to folder.  No problems with those, but for some reason, my program throws the above exception.

I use the following command on the Team City API to get the file:
https://{myserver}/httpAuth/repository/downloadAll/{myrepository}/{buildId}:id/artifacts.zip

Does anybody know why this would have just started happening on February 1, 2021?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up a bug on the JetBrains Team City site describing the above problem.  They responded this morning with a fix.  This appears to have been introduced with TeamCity Enterprise 2020.2.2 (build 85899):

**Please add an [internal property](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-teamcity-server-startup-properties.html#TeamCity+internal+properties):** (Click blue link to the left for instructions on how)

```
teamcity.internal.artifacts.useZip64=false
```

We applied the above property, and the problem was immediately resolved.  No reboot of TeamCity was necessary.

Here is a [LINK](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-69951) to the bug/solution on the JetBrains TeamCity site.